# MSVC - How can I find out if a type must be moved?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012

I seem to be having problems with a compiler/library bug. When I try

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

int main() 
{
    typedef std::unique_ptr<int> T;

    std::cout << "is_copy_assignable: " 
              << std::is_copy_assignable<T>::value 
              << "\n"
              << "is_copy_constructible: " 
              << std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value << "\n";
}
```

with Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 I get

```
is_copy_assignable: 1
is_copy_constructible: 1
```

instead of

```
is_copy_assignable: 0
is_copy_constructible: 0
```

Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: One more related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135409/why-does-is-copy-constructible-return-true-for-unique-ptr-in-msvc12

Answer (score 3):

This is most certainly a **bug** of MS's implementation of either `std::unique_ptr<>` or of the type traits. Those type traits should work as you expect (see a live example [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/188WMz%248)).

Comment: I think that code also fails with a public copy ctor.

Answer (score 3):

If you look down into what is happening, it checks for whether the assignment operator and ctor **exists** and that is all. In MSVC's implementation, the copy constructor and assignment operator are `private` in `std::unique_ptr`'s implementation. However it does not do any access checking. MSVC has not implemented `= delete`, etc. which is why it returns `true`.

After playing with it for a while, I think I have something that should work for detecting private copy ctor:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
struct wrap
{
   T t;
};

template<typename T, typename = int>
struct is_copyable : std::false_type { };

template<typename T>
struct is_copyable<T, 
    decltype(wrap<T>(std::declval<const wrap<T>&>()), 0)> : std::true_type
{};

class X
{
   public:
   X(const X&) {}
};

class Y
{
   Y(const Y&){}
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(is_copyable<std::unique_ptr<int>>::value, "Error!");
    static_assert(is_copyable<X>::value, "Error!");
    static_assert(is_copyable<Y>::value, "Error!");
}
```

[Example on LWS](http://liveworkspace.org/code/188WMz%2450).

**However**, this caused an [ICE](http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp) with MSVC... so doesn't work.